# I want to add a new value in my list in response body

Tags: flutter, dart

```
product_sp.add(newItemPrice);

http.Response response = await client.patch(url,

    body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
       "records": [
{
      "id": orderId,
  "fields": {
  "product_sp": product_sp,
  }
    }
       ]
    },
    ));

 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
  print(data);
} else {
  throw Exception();
}
```

> I am trying to add a new item in the product_sp and patching it but it results into an exception.

This is the response body of product_sp right now-
product_sp: [L, test]

response.body generatig error:

I/flutter ( 6545): {error: Invalid payload, details: Error: body.records[0] is not a Record; body.records[0].fields.product_sp is not a CellValue; body.records[0].fields.product_sp is none of number, string, boolean, null, 1 more; body.records[0].fields.product_sp[0] is not a GristObjCode; body.records[0].fields.product_sp[0] is not a valid enum value}

Answer (score 0):

you can use `List.generate` like

```
"fields": {
    "list_one": List<int>.generate(array.length, (index)=>index),
  }
```

For generating random int array with random length which generates int between 1-100 with the length of upto 100 (change max length) . here is the code

```
"fields": {
    "list_one": List<int>.generate(Random().nextInt(100), (index) => Random().nextInt(100)),
  }
```

Comment: This is not working because it is generating values 1 to n but I want to patch a random new value in this list, can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: is value depends on some value or you want to generate random int values?

Comment: so I have edited the answer which is generating random int with random length

Comment: or do you want to add more map values like list_one, list_two etc ?

Comment: Sorry for my misleading question, I have edited it properly now, please help me.

Comment: do 1 thing.... `print(response.body);` in else statement rather than exception and also do mention where you want to add data in product_sp... inside body ??? or where you are already adding

Comment: Okay, yes I wanted to add data inside body.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242070/discussion-between-rifa-and-arslan-kaleem).